# php MAX MySQL Query not echoing

Tags: php, mysql, max

The below displays nothing.  I simply want to pull the MAX number between two dates.  The SQL Query actually works, and the dates are fine as they are used in other queries.  It just doesn't seem to work with the `MAX` selector.

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","pw");
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

//Other queries before this..
$query5="SELECT MAX(TOTALVISITS) FROM mytable WHERE DATE between '$mystartdate' and '$thedbdate'";

$result5=mysql_query($query5);
mysql_close();

$maxtotal=mysql_result($result5);

echo $MAX TOTAL: " . $maxtotal;
```

Comment: `thedbdate` should be `$thedbdate` ??? try echoing `mysql_num_rows($result5)` to ensure the count is 1 as you expect

Comment: The format of the query works for me on a table of my own, so you must be passing it in wrong. Does it work when you put the query into a MySQL GUI? Try print_r($query5); and give it a go.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` is 1 and I edited question to include `$` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First, don't call `mysql_close()` after `mysql_query()`.  Your result set won't be available for fetch.

```
$result5=mysql_query($query5);
// DON'T DO THIS!
//mysql_close();
```

[`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-result.php) takes at least two parameters - the resource and the row you want to retrieve, and optionally the column you want to retrieve. Since you have only one, the column can technically be omitted.

```
// Get the first column of the first row from the result set.
$maxvisits = mysql_result($result5, 0, 0);
```

Note, it is good practice to assign an alias to a calculated or aggregate column:

```
$query5="SELECT MAX(TOTALVISITS) AS maxvisits FROM mytable WHERE DATE between '$mystartdate' and '$thedbdate'";
//------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes it easier to use functions like [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), which can be a little more flexible than `mysql_result()`:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5);
echo $row['maxvisits'];
```

Comment: This was it,  Although I was unaware of the two extra parameters, it was not needed seeing the result only had 1 row, thank you.